# CSS menu transitions not working

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, menu, transition

I'm trying to add some transition effects onto my css dropdown menu, but wherever I put the transition code in it doesn't seem to work.

```
transition: all 2s ease-in;
```

I'm trying to get the transition to fade in and out on hover of the parent li of the actual dropdown ul so that the event doesn't happen so suddenly.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JazParkyn/6jshy/5/

Comment: Are you open to adding jQuery, because this is easily done with some scripts.

Comment: @DiederikEEn Jaz made his comment to me clearly, its unnecessary to add your opinion towards someone elses decision.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot transition the `display` property. Try using `opacity` for your dropdown menus.

```css
nav ul ul {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: all .5s ease-in;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: all .5s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in;
}
nav ul li:hover > ul {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6jshy/12/).

Comment: exactly what i was after, thankyou. chosen as accepted answer due to the all keyword and the use of various webkit extensions.

Comment: Really useful. I didn't know you could not transition display and this is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

fiddle :[here](http://jsfiddle.net/6jshy/16/)

you have misplaced the transition. It needs to be on `nav ul li` to activate. Aslo you migh missed some webkits which i added for you.

//update

Comment: thanks, but that makes the transition happen on the background of the li tags, i'm aiming to get the transition on the visibility of the dropdown

Comment: @DiederikEEn Please do not copy [my answer and fiddle](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16546221/1493698).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot transition `display`, use `visibility` and `opacity` instead:

```
nav ul ul {
    visibility: hidden; /* fallback for old browsers */
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 2s ease-in;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

[Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6jshy/17/).

If you want the transition to only apply to `opacity`, you need to specify `visibility` too, which makes it a bit more complex:

```
nav ul ul {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 2s 0s ease-in, visibility 0s 2s;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 2s 0s ease-in, visibility 0s 0s;
}
```

[Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6jshy/14/).

Answer (score 0):

fiddle : [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6jshy/9/)

i've added effect on `a:hover` and the dropdown menu, you can change delay etc...